# C# function error (object reference)

Tags: c#, function, object, reference

pretty straight-forward question, I get an error I don't know how to solve, in Visual C# Express, when I call the Romberg function in my main (I provided the error message at the appropriate line). I tried using this.Romberg too but it didn't help. What should I do differently?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Romberg2
{
    class test
    {
        // the function
        double f(double x)
        {
            double f;
            f=8*(Math.Sqrt(1-x*x)-x);
            return f;
        }

        // The Integration function
        void Romberg(double a, double b, int n, double[,] R)
        {
            int i, j, k;
            double h, sum;

            h = b - a;
            R[0,0]=(h/2)*(f(a)+f(b));

            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                h=h/2;
                sum=0;

                for (k=1; k <= (Math.Pow(2.0,i)-1); k +=2)
                    sum +=f(a+k*h);

                R[i,0]=R[i-1,0]/2+sum*h;

                for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
                    R[i,j]=R[i,j-1]+(R[i,j-1]-R[i-1,j-1])/(Math.Pow(4.0,j)-1);
            }
        }

        static void main(int argc, char [] argv)
        {
            double[,] R = new double [10,10];
            int n=5, digits=13;
            double a=0, b=1/Math.Sqrt(2.0);

            // Call the integrating function
            Romberg(a, b, n, R);//ERROR: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

            // Printout the diagram
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(R[i,j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add static to void Romberg -> static void Romberg

Comment: @Marc Finally something I knew the answer too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1) Main is not the correct format.  It needs to be in one of these formats:

```
static void Main() {...} 
static void Main(string[] args) {... } 
static int Main() {...} 
static int Main(string [] args) {...}
```

Just change it to 'static void Main()'

2) Make Romberg method static

```
static void Romberg(double a, double b, int n, double[,] R)
```

3) Make f method static:

```
static double f(double x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Romberg is not a static method ,so you should call it via an instance using the new keyword

```
new test().Romberg(a, b, n, R);
```

or simply make it a static function

```
static void Romberg(double a, double b, int n, double[,] R)
```

Answer (score 2):

`main` is static, so it can't call instance methods. Declare `Romberg` as static, or create an instance of `test` and use that instance:

```
var inst = new test();
inst.Romberg(a, b, n, R);
```

For more information, please check out the MSDN article on [Static Classes and Static Class Members.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`Main` is a static method, `Roomberg` is an instance method. Either create a new instance of the class inside `Main` and call it through the instance, or make `Roomberg` static also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `Romberg` function static, or you could wrap it in it's own class, instantiate that and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call that method on an instance. That method belongs to instance of the class.

```
var inst = new test();
inst.Romberg(q, w, e, R);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. To call `Romberg(a, b, n, R);` you have to create `test` class object first. `Romberg` is a instance method.

```
test obj=new test();
obj.Romberg(a, b, n, R);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are tryin to call method from class that is not initializedt.

```
 static void Romberg(double a, double b, int n, double[,] R)
```